# Return two data frames from a function with data frame format

Tags: python, function, dataframe, return, jupyter-notebook

I want to return two data frames from a function, like this:

```
def test():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], ['a','b','c'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([4,5,6], ['d','e','f'])
    return df1
    return df2
test()
```

But the function only returns one data frame df1. How to return both in pretty data frame format, not in cmd black background format?

When I tried to return both using

```
return df1, df2
```

in the Jupyter Notebook, the output returns the data frames in a black background cmd-like format, and not in proper data frame format.

Comment: I think you should just have one return statement. return df1, df2

Comment: @TrippCannella That is what I don't want. It returns both in black background like cmd. I am using Jupyter Notebook btw. I want the data frames to be returned in proper table format.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

How about this:

```
def test():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], ['a','b','c'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([4,5,6], ['d','e','f'])
    return df1, df2

a, b = test()
display(a, b)
```

This prints out:

```
    0
a   1
b   2
c   3

    0
d   4
e   5
f   6
```

Answer (score -1):

Call IPython (module) in it display(module) and then import display(function) from it

```
from IPython.display import display
```