# how to return two dataframes in a single function

Tags: python, pandas, function, return

I'm crawling data through api and I need to get 2 dataframes through 1 function simultaneously. However, the code I wrote below failed to do the task. How can I modify it so as to get two dfs in one function?

```
def get_qa(question):
num = 1
row = []
people = []
for ans in question.answers:
     if num< question.answer_count:
            a = get_answer_data()
            b = get_author()
            s = {**a,**b}
            row.append(s)
            pt = get_people_detail()
            people.append(pt)
            num+=1
            #time.sleep(random.randint(0,2))
df_qa = pd.DataFrame(row)
df_people = pd.DataFrame(people)
return df_qa,df_people
```

--------Update--------
Thanks for all of your help.
after use  `a, b = get_qa(question)`I can get two dfs successfully.However, the dataframe I've got seems only receive the last item in the list.

```
<bound method NDFrame.add_prefix of       ans_id                         author_id author_name business  \
0  572182013  16b179b9de836c121ace0aabdd2611a0         钱二胖     市场推广   
1  572182013  16b179b9de836c121ace0aabdd2611a0         钱二胖     市场推广   
2  572182013  16b179b9de836c121ace0aabdd2611a0         钱二胖     市场推广   
3  572182013  16b179b9de836c121ace0aabdd2611a0         钱二胖     市场推广   
4  572182013  16b179b9de836c121ace0aabdd2611a0         钱二胖     市场推广   
5  572182013  16b179b9de836c121ace0aabdd2611a0         钱二胖     市场推广
```

The lenth of df is corrent(the original  data contains 6 items)Is the problem evoked by the return?
Or it's the way I calling the function should be responsible for the failure?

Comment: Can you show how you're calling your function ? Also fix your indentation :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568474/return-two-data-frames-from-a-function-with-data-frame-format

Comment: It is hard to guess. You are not using ans within your for loop. You might get always the same result from get_answer_data(). It could help if you give more information.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the indentation which I am sure you have taken care of nothing seems wrong. Are you catching both the data frames when you are calling the function? You should try something like below. calling the function would only show the first dataframe in the output.

```
df_qa, df_people = get_qa(questions)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should actually work if your lhs is also a tuple.

```
def get_qa():
    return 4, 5

a, b = get_qa()
print(a, b)
```

prints out

```
4 5
```